# Formik - How to reset form after confirmation

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik

In [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik), how to make the Reset button reset the form only **after confirmation**?

My code below still resets the form even when you click Cancel.

```
var handleReset = (values, formProps) => {
    return window.confirm('Reset?'); // still resets after you Cancel :(
};

return (
  <Formik onReset={handleReset}>
    {(formProps) => { 
      return (
        <Form>
          ...
          <button type='reset'>Reset</button>
        </Form>
      )}}
  </Formik>
);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm not completely certain, but I think you will have to write your own reset function without a button with a `reset` type. Something like this:

```
const handleReset = (resetForm) => {
  if (window.confirm('Reset?')) {
    resetForm();
  }
};

function Example() {
  return (
    <Formik initialValues={{ value: 1 }}>
      {formProps => {
        return (
          <Form>
            <Field name="value" type="number" />
            <button
              onClick={handleReset.bind(null, formProps.resetForm)}
              type="button"
            >
              Reset
            </button>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

If you really want to use `onReset`, I think the only way is to throw an error. The Formik [source code](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/blob/c5243947fcf21cd873dd86b57689a30ffc46eab8/src/Formik.tsx#L548) seems to indicate `resetForm()` will be called no matter what your `onReset()` function returns.

```
const handleReset = () => {
  if (!window.confirm('Reset?')) {
    throw new Error('Cancel reset');
  }
};

function Example() {
  return (
    <Formik initialValues={{ value: 1 }} onReset={handleReset}>
      {formProps => {
        return (
          <Form>
            <Field name="value" type="number" />
            <button type="reset">
              Reset
            </button>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
}
```

I would still go with the first solution though personally.

Comment: Thank you MadScone. Yeah you could do that, but Formik already have `onReset`, so I thought there should be a way to do it there

Comment: I updated my answer with a possible solution if you really want to use `onReset`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking at the source code, that looks like a Formik limitation. I'll go with your first solution :)

Answer (score 176):

Hello @Aximili you can use [`resetForm`](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#resetform-nextinitialstate-formikstate-values-void) in onSubmit.

```
onSubmit={(values, { resetForm }) => {

      // do your stuff 
      resetForm();

}}
```

**what `resetForm` can do?**

Imperatively reset the form. This will clear errors and touched, set isSubmitting to false, isValidating to false, and rerun mapPropsToValues with the current WrappedComponent's props or what's passed as an argument. The latter is useful for calling resetForm within componentWillReceiveProps.

Comment: This is a better answer than the one accepted by OP

Answer (score 17):

I understand OP's question was for `Formik`.

However, for anyone using `useFormik` hook and wanting to clear form on 'reset' button click, here's one way to achieve that.

`<button type="reset"  onClick={ e => formik.resetForm()}> Reset</button>`

Comment: I came to this article looking for this answer. This was exactly what I needed, because React Hooks.

Answer (score 8):

in 2023
`formik.resetForm();` this worked for me.

here is the complete code for `onSubmit` event

```
  onSubmit:(values)=>{
const name = values.name;
      const mobile = values.mobile;
      const website = values.website;
      const service = values.service;
      const msg = values.msg;
  
axios.post('/api/SendContactForm', {name, mobile, website, service, msg})
      .then(function (response) {
           //console.log(response);
              toast.success(' Thanks for the message. We will contact you asap.');
              formik.resetForm();
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
            formik.resetForm();
            toast.error(error.message || error.statusText);
          });
     
  
      }
  
  });
```

Comment: You can simplify the code by adding a `finally` callback handler to the Promise that resets the form, so you don't need to do it twice.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution:

```
<Formik
initialValues={initialValues}
onSubmit={async (values, { resetForm }) => {
  await onSubmit(values)
  resetForm()
}}>
```

Reset the form on submit immediately.

I'm not using a custom wrapper around Formik.

Comment: this is great if you don't need a button like the OP requested.
I ended up doing similar to this, but in the  'const onSubmit' declaration. 
And I wanted to keep the filled form data, so just did actions.setSubmitting(false) rather than reseting the whole form.

Answer (score 3):

My issue was I did not wanted to use window.confirm(). I wanted to use my own modal so I used

> useFormikContext()

You can create a function component like this

```
let resetPresForm = {};// You will have to define this before useEffect

const ResettingForm = () => {
    const { resetForm } = useFormikContext();
    resetPresForm = resetForm; // Store the value of resetForm in this variable
    return null;
};
```

Now Import this function component inside your

```
<Formik>
     <button type="button" onClick={() => { setShowResetModal(true) }} className="comman-btn">Reset</button>
     <ResettingForm />
</Formik>
```

Now on modal component confirm you can

```
const resetPrescriptionForm = () => {
    setShowResetModal(false);
    resetPresForm();
}
```

[Reference](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormikContext)

Answer (score 3):

I used `actions.resetForm()` and It resolved the problem.

```
onSubmit={(values, actions) => {

     actions.resetForm();

}}
```

Comment: This is 100% the right way to do it. Thanks @Shirp!

Answer (score 1):

```
     onSubmit: async (values, actions) => {
    actions.resetForm();
  },
```

You must add two parameters and use second parameter. So you can try **actions.resetForm();**

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to do this is just passing a onSubmit handler and using the 2nd parameter, being the formik helpers, within it:

```
const handleOnSubmitSubmit = async ( values: Values, { resetForm }: FormikHelpers<Values>
  ) => {
    try {
 
      // your code 
      resetForm()


    } catch {
     // your code
    }
 }
```

In the TSX:

```
<Formik
 onSubmit={handleCreateCompanySubmit}
>
 {/* your code */}
 </Formik>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I created a **Formik event** of **onReset={handleFormReset}** & inside **form props**, passed **handleReset** for **onReset event of form** like this-

```
            <Formik
            onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}
            initialValues={initialValues}
            validationSchema={checkoutSchema}
            onReset={handleFormReset}
        >
            {({
                values,
                errors,
                touched,
                handleBlur,
                handleChange,
                handleSubmit,
                handleReset
            }) => (
                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} onReset={handleReset}>
```

Then I created a button with type='reset', like

```
<Button type="reset" color="warning" variant="contained" sx={{ mr: 3 }}>
   Reset
</Button>
```

Finally, I created the handler function handleFormReset(values), where I emptied the values object if user confirms inside a **confirm box**.

```
    const handleFormReset = values => {
    if (window.confirm("Do You Want To Reset?")) {
        values = {};
    }
};
```